# How to correctly retrieve redirection url on callback from capacitor browser in ionic app

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, oauth

I am trying to use ionic capacitor browser plugin for oauth flow but the browser return an empty object instead of the expected token or code string from the auth server.

I have tried using a custom urlscheme. The expected result is that the plugin should return an object url which should contain the 'code' but nothing is returned

```
    async openPage(){
        App.addListener('appUrlOpen', (data) => {
        console.log('Data: '+JSON.stringify(data));
        })
        await Browser.open({url: myUrl})

        this.addRedirectListener();
     }

    private async addRedirectListener() {
       App.addListener('appUrlOpen', async (data: any) => {
       console.debug('AppComponent - constructor - appUrlOpen');
       if(data.url.indexOf('callback#')!=-1) {
       let regEx = /(callback#access_token=)(.*)/g;
       let code = regEx.exec(data.url)[2];
       console.log(code);
       }
      await Browser.close();
      });
  }
```

Return an empty object instead of the expected object which should have been a token or code string.
I have tried using the app plugin to track an event when the redirect uri is triggered.

I expect to return an object with token or code string but returns an empty object

Comment: I successfully managed to get the OAuth callback URL from an Azure B2C login "token" flow. I think this may work for other login providers as well. 
I used this plugin to trigger an external browser window: https://github.com/moberwasserlechner/capacitor-oauth2 and then using the addListener, the URL contained the token

Comment: maggix can you share sample code for this .

Comment: Code sample would be great

Answer (score 4):

> Using Cordova Plugins and Ionic Native

I've used cordova inAppBrowser Plugin with capacitor. working absolutely fine.
we can use some of cordova plugin along with capacitor

Please read this

https://capacitorjs.com/docs/v2/cordova/using-cordova-plugins

Step 1 : Install cordova inappbrowser plugin with capacitor

```
npm install cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
npm install @ionic-native/in-app-browser
ionic cap sync
npm install --save @ionic-native/core
```

Step 2:
Import Modules file on app.module.ts and add it in providers

Step 3: Use this demo code

```
async openBrowser() {
const options: InAppBrowserOptions = {
  location: 'no',
  clearcache: 'yes',
  zoom: 'yes',
  toolbar: 'yes',
  closebuttoncaption: 'close'
};
const browser = this.iab.create('https://google.com', '_blank', options);
console.log('opended');
console.log('browser=>');
this.util.errorToast('Opened');
browser.on('loadstop').subscribe(event => {
  console.log('event?;>11', event);
  this.util.errorToast(event.url);
  const navUrl = event.url;
  console.log(navUrl.includes('facebook'), navUrl.includes('instagram'));
  if (navUrl.includes('facebook') || navUrl.includes('instagram') || navUrl.includes('checkout')) {
    console.log('close');
    this.util.errorToast('Closed ddddd');
    browser.close();
  }
});
console.log('browser=> end');
```

}

Comment: I used the 'npx' command instead of 'ionic'